# How do I work around a font issue in text extraction using iTextSharp Core?

Tags: pdf, itext7

I'm trying to extract text from this PDF file:

http://www.in.gov/legislative/iac/T03270/A00200.PDF

The error I'm getting:

```
PDF Extraction Error
Dictionary doesn't have supported font data.

iText.Kernel.Exceptions.PdfException

at iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(PdfDictionary fontDictionary)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.GetFont(PdfDictionary fontDict)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.SetTextFontOperator.Invoke(PdfCanvasProcessor processor, PdfLiteral operator, IList`1 operands)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral operator, IList`1 operands)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfResources resources)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessPageContent(PdfPage page)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfPage page, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy, IDictionary`2 additionalContentOperators)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfPage page, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)
```

Is there a way to work around this? Using the Simple extraction strategy, why would it need to care about fonts?

I've also tried a Location-based extraction strategy -- same result.

Unfortunately, it's a government document, so if it's somehow corrupt, I have no control over it. I've extracted text from hundreds of other documents on the same site without issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a way to still extract using iText -- without having to fix it by exporting from a PDF reader that is more promiscuous. Since every reader I can find seems to display it correctly, I have to imagine this is either some PDF nuance iText isn't aware of, or it's an error that should be recoverable.

Wasn't aware that PDFs use a glyph map to the font, I assumed they were mostly ASCII plaintext with some escape sequence for upper characters. TIL

Comment: The document uses a simple font with WinAnsi encoding, nothing special, so there shouldn't be any problems with text extraction. Possibly a bug in iTextSharp Core but iText support can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what font issue you are seeing, but I have a program that extracts text from PDFs and I used the document you referenced, https://iac.iga.in.gov/iac//T03270/A00200.PDF, and was able to extract text from every page without the program throwing any exception. Take a peak of what I'm using below and see if that gives you any issue. I have a link to a working console application using this code at this link [here](https://www.debugandrelease.com/how-to-scan-a-pdf-for-text-using-csharp/).

```cs
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;

namespace ScanTextInPDFs
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string executingDirectory = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

            byte[] bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync($"{executingDirectory}PDFs\\A00200.pdf");
            string textToFind = "Lorem ipsum";
            bool foundText = false;

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                using PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(memoryStream);
                using PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
                {
                    PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.GetPage(page);
                    string pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfPage, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

                    if (pageText.Contains(textToFind, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        foundText = true;
                }
            }

            if (foundText)
                Console.WriteLine($"Found '{textToFind}' in the pdf.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"Did not find '{textToFind}' in the pdf.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is output of my program finding text in this PDF.
[image]